# Postgresql: парсинг JSON параметра функции

Tags: postgresql

Моя функция имеет параметр типа JSON. Подскажите пожалуйста, как получить значение какого-то элемента этого параметра внутри функции?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "public"."my_function"("user_data" jsonb)
RETURNS "pg_catalog"."int4" AS $BODY$

DECLARE name varchar;
DECLARE email varchar;

BEGIN

/* Мне необходимо получить значение например user_data->'UserName', user_data->'UserEmail' и присвоить их например переменным */

END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100
```

Не пойму как это синтаксически сделать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Любыми подходящими операторами: [стандартными](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) или самодельными. Есть стандартный оператор `->>` возвращающий указанный ключ JSON в виде текстового типа.

```
name := user_data->>'UserName';
email := user_data->>'UserEmail';
```

или

```
select user_data->>'UserName',
    user_data->>'UserEmail'
into name, email;
```

Как больше нравится.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, как раз с селектом сражался, "INTO name, email" - вот он необходимый мне момент! еще раз спасибо!